# Transaction Management in Spring-Integration framework and apache Camel

Tags: spring, transactions, integration, apache-camel, spring-integration

I'm browsing Integration frameworks to choose the best one for my integration problem. one thing that I want to know is transaction management in multiple application integration context, supported or not ? and if it does, how ? in [Pro Spring Integration](http://www.apress.com/9781430233459) I didn't find a clear solution they just put sth like

```
<int:poller fixed-rate="1000">
<int:transactional/>
</int:poller>
```

and I couldn't understand how this manage transaction along multiple application ?

could anyone expert in these frameworks help me to find out to know that how transaction management and recovery in case of error in any application that transaction is executing can be done using these frameworks ?
for example consider this scenario : application A initiate transaction and use applications B and C in middle and finally do sth after B and C and commit it, if in this scenario application c fails or throw an exception, is there anyway to rollback transaction in B and A and how ?

Answer (score 1):

for Camel, see theses links on implementing transacted routes and error handling strategies

http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html

http://camel.apache.org/error-handling-in-camel.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to these links above from Ben, then the Camel in Action book, has a full chapter covering using transactions with Camel, chapter 9.

There is a free excerpt of the chapter 9 sponsored by FuseSource at: http://fusesource.com/collateral/88